# Как обратиться к методу не создавая экземпляра класс?

Tags: c#, класс

У меня есть форма CheckersForm и есть класс LogicGame. В CheckersForm  я произвожу некие действия, а точнее сохраняю кнопки со значениями в FieldButton[,] fieldButtons; затем когда захожу в LogicGame, то там, чтобы обратиться к CheckersForm, создаю экземпляр этого класс CheckersForm cf = new CheckersForm(); И, естественно, работает всё отлично, только вот данных про мои кнопки в cf уже нет.

Как мне быть? Может свойства использовать? Но я не очень понимаю как.

```
public partial class CheckersForm : Form
    {
        const int cellSize = 50;
        const int mapSize = 8;
        private delegate void printer(string data);
        Checker[,] arrChecker;
        printer Printer;
        FieldButton[,] fieldButtons;
        private Thread _clientThread;
        public FieldButton[,] FieldButtons { get => fieldButtons; }
        Image whiteFigure;
        Image blackFigure;
        LogicGame lg;
        Field field;
    public void GameStart()
    {
        fieldButtons = new FieldButton[mapSize, mapSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                FieldButton btn = new FieldButton();
                btn.Location = new Point(j * cellSize, i * cellSize);
                btn.Size = new Size(cellSize, cellSize);
                btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(FieldButtonClick);
                btn.X = btn.Location.X;
                btn.Y = btn.Location.Y;
                btn.BackColor = GetPrevButColor(btn);
                fieldButtons[i, j] = btn;
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
        
    }
    public void UpdateBoardd(string data)
    {
        string coords = data;
        var reg = new Regex(@"(?<open>\%).*?(?<final-open>\%)");
        var matches = reg.Matches(coords).Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups["final"].Value).ToList();
        foreach (string strCoords in matches)
        {
            coords = strCoords;
        }
        string[] subs = coords.Split(',');
        string ast = subs[0];
        string bst = subs[1];
        int a = int.Parse(ast);
        int b = int.Parse(bst);
        foreach (var btn in fieldButtons)
        {
            if ((btn.Location.X == a) && (btn.Location.Y == b))
            {

                lg.ActionsWithBoard(btn);
            }
        }
    }
```

А вот LogicGame

```
 public class LogicGame
    {
        private Socket _serverSocket;
        Chat chat;
        CheckersForm cf = new CheckersForm();
        Field field;
        FieldButton[,] arrayChecker;
        const int cellSize = 50;
        public LogicGame()
        {
            field = new Field();
            arrayChecker = cf.FieldButtons;
            //field.GenerateField();
        }
```

Как правильно этим всем управляться, по идее можно было бы сделать класс LogicGame статическим, но тогда там столько кода полетит к чертям, мне кажется static это не выход.

Comment: Ответ вам уже дали, добавлю пару комментариев. Первый - по неймингу: на заборе написано Validate - а на самом деле там Save, это про ваш класс Checker'а который на самом деле ни разу не чекер. Второй - у вас начато отделение логики от инфраструктуры и это хорошо, но не закончено, game logic слишком сильно завязан на winforms. Захочешь портировать на wpf - и придётся либо дублировать код, либо половину переписывать, а уж под веб - и подавно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это самая попсовая ошибка тех, кто начинает писать ООП код не зная ООП. Передавайте экземпляр формы в конструктор.

```cs
public class LogicGame
{
    CheckersForm cf;
    public LogicGame(CheckersForm form)
    {
        cf = form;
    }
}
```

А экземпляр `LogicGame` создавайте так

```cs
lg = new LogicGame(this);
```

Comment: я чувствовал, что здесь что-то такое, понятное и элементарное но да, я ещё мал и глуп в ооп, спасибо, очень помогло))

Comment: Привет, вроде всё понял, когда ты написал, но сейчас я снова в ступоре, я передал экземпляр в один класс, а как это же передать в другой класс? т.о. У меня есть допустим одна форма и 2 класса, мне нужно создавать два конструктора?

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев если у вас появился новый вопрос - задайте его отдельно, с подробностями и кодом. И у конструктора может быть несколько аргументов как и у любого другого метода.

Comment: хорошо, я создал новую тему)